# excel formula: return true if none of the cells in the range are blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, excel-formula, notnull

I want to return true if a range of cells (A2:K2) doesnt contain any blanks. So all the cells in the given range must contain something.

I can count the number of cells that contains something but im not sure what to do next?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2:K2)>0)*1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNTBLANK` to count the blank cells in conjunction with an `IF` formula:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A2:K2)=0,TRUE,FALSE)
```